# Drop partition scheme with orphan indexes

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, dependencies

I have a partition scheme in my SQL Server database that I am trying to drop. This scheme was used by 2 indexes, which I deleted.

I can't delete the scheme, since it appears to still be used by the indexes, even though they don't exist anymore.

Running the following query:

```
select object_name(i.object_id), i.name, i.index_id
FROM   sys.indexes i
JOIN   sys.partition_schemes ps ON i.data_space_id = ps.data_space_id
WHERE  ps.name = 'CallScheme'
```

I get the names of the 2 tables that had the indexes, but the index names are NULL (and index id is 0).

How do I get rid of these indexes so that I can drop the partition scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but the index names are NULL (and index id is 0)

**That's because they are heaps**.  [BOL Reference on `sys.indexes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo066bd9ac-6554-4297-88fe-d740de1f94a8.aspx)

One way to get these off of that partition scheme would be to create a clustered index for those tables and specify a different filegroup or another partition scheme.  Then once you have those tables off of that partition scheme you should be able to continue with removing it.

```
create clustered index IX_YourIndex
on dbo.YourTable (YourCiKeyCol)
on SomeOtherFilegroup;
```

Comment: Surely the `on SomeOtherFileGroup` is not important in this case?  Just creating a clustered index on the same filegroup should still move the data, removing the dependency on the partition scheme, no?  I could certainly be wrong - it wouldn't be the first time!

Comment: Correct, I was explicit just to solidify a point.

Comment: Cool - I just wanted to make sure since for many databases, having a 2nd filegroup is not necessary.